# Clone CSS styling for Google Docs

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I am making a Google Apps Script for Google Docs with a side panel.

I would like to match the style of buttons, scroll bars, etc. that Google Docs has.

[image]

FYI, a lot of the CSS seems to have be minified/obfuscated.

```
scb-button-icon
jfk-star
```

Where might I find such a thing?

I would have thought Google Apps Script might have provided something like this, since consistency makes the UX better.

If the official source is not available, is an unofficial one available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Sidebar CSS is now freely available, see [CSS Package for Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/css).

---

For research only, of course:

- View Source of the page you wish to research. Copy and...
- Paste into a text editor. Remove everything up to and including the `<style>` tag, and from the `</style>` tag to the end. Copy and...
- Paste into an [HTML decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/decode.aspx), to remove the encoding. Now you have all the CSS, it's just badly formatted. Copy and...
- Paste into a [CSS Formatter](http://cleancss.com/), and tidy it up. Optionally, output as a file.

At this point, you've got a CSS file that can be experimentally built into your for-personal-use-only app. Browser inspectors are handy for determining the HTML others have used to produce the UI elements you want to learn from.

Here's my own little experiment, a sidebar in a Google Doc, with an assortment of elements:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I had actually just got finished doing this. FYI, I kept only the parts of the CSS that I wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Enjoy the bounty.

Comment: Thanks - that's the first one I've tried for! Funny thing - I had been through this exercise the first day that sidebar support was added to Docs, and hadn't done much else with it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you'll be able to find the source code, so here is an alternative:

[CSS Unminify](http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/)

This tool will take minified CSS and expand it. This will allow you to at the very least read the CSS and hopefully figure out which rules you need.

Answer (score 0):

If copyright infringement is not an issue then you could simply recreate the design that Google adopt for their buttons. It should be fairly simple with CSS. The font Google + uses is called Roboto and is [free to download](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto)

Answer (score 0):

I talked to some of the guys at Google and got a [alpha version of the CSS](https://googledrive.com/host/0B0G1UdyJGrY6XzdjQWF4a1JYY1k/add-ons.css).

It does not yet, however, completely support IE or Firefox, and has (very minor) differences, so I accepted Mogsdad's answer.