# Copying text from email and pasting in Google Doc using Google Script App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I spent about 3 days looking at this.  What I intend to do is collect emails that are sent to me and paste them at the top of a Google Doc, sort of like a running archive.

So the first phase of me trying to do this is complete.  I was able to get text from an email and put it in google docs.  The next part is trying to keep the format of the text AND placing a page break after the text.  The below function allows me to get text from an email (I found a way to get HTML for email as well but can't seem to paste it correctly in the Google Doc)

```
function getEmailBody() {
  var message
  var searchedEmailThreads = GmailApp.search('label:announcement')
  
  ... code to search emails, returning searchEmailThreads array ...

  message = searchedEmailThreads[0].getMessages()[0]
  var oldBodyHTML = message.getPlainBody();
  // var oldBodyHTML = message.getBody() - gets html format but how can I paste it in the doc?

  return oldBodyHTML
}
```

The below function is to write it to the Google Doc.  I know it is inserttext but I haven't found a way to insert as formatted text.

```
function writeToDocument(htmlBody) {
   var document = DocumentApp.openById({document_ID})

  document.getBody().editAsText().insertText(0, htmlBody)
  // document.appendParagraph("A paragraph.")
  // document.appendPageBreak()
}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I paste into Google Doc as formatted text?  Do I need to save the getBody() in an HTML file?
2. How can I apply a page break at the end of the text mentioned that I just copied from the email?

Please and thank you ahead of time for any help that you can give!

Comment: [page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74569869/insert-page-breaks-in-google-docs-with-app-script)

Comment: [css styling for google docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207020/clone-css-styling-for-google-docs/20365348#20365348)

Comment: @Cooper on the pagebreak page, it mentions Google Doc API but I'm using DocumentApp.  Before posting this, I read online that the difference between the two was mainly that with Google Doc API, you can manage readwrite permissions.  Is that right?  That's why I went with DocumentApp because I saw more resources with it.

For your second comment, how can I use that to paste HTML into a Google Doc?

Comment: DocumentApp = Document Service .  FYI

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `keep the format of the text`, `formatted text`, and `save the getBody() in an HTML file`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.